# Why do I get "Wi-fi is disabled by hardware switch" after upgrade to 13.04?

Tags: wireless, 13.04, rfkill

Just got an ASUS 1015e with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. Decided to upgrade to 13.04 (started by upgrading to 12.11). Did both upgrades with wireless no problem. When computer restarted with 13.04, WiFi was disconnected, and now says *Wi-fi is disabled by hardware switch*.

Ran `rfkill list`, and it shows:

```
Phys as hardware switch blocked: yes.
```

Contacted ASUS customer service - they say no such thing as a hardware switch on the 1015e.

Any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a switch then usually a key combination turns it on like fn +f2. You may have to go to the manufacturers site and look at the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, tried that several times - still not working.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.